# How to redraw partially in opengl Es 2.0

Tags: opengl-es, 3d

As per my need I want to redraw only some part of the scene for each frame instead
of redrawing the entire scene only if some portion of it is updated.

Is there a way to do that in OpenGL ES 2.0?
Please any input on this will be really helpful

Comment: You can set a viewport to draw to a specific rectangle of the buffer. You will need to set the matrices accordingly though.

Comment: Hi Matic Thank you very much for your reply. I am relatively new to opengles please can you explain your answer in a little detail.

Comment: Your question is a bit too general to answer at all. The point is you may set a specific viewport to set on what part of the buffer you are drawing. This is usually set to (0, 0, bufferWidth, bufferHeight) to draw to a whole buffer. To draw to a specific part of the buffer you may set some other parameters to this method for instance (bufferWidth*.5f, bufferHeight*.5f, bufferWidth*.5f, bufferHeight*.5f) which would draw only to a bottom right quarter of the buffer. Rest depends on your matrix system such as using "ortho"  would need new relative coordinates as what is "left", "right", "top"...

Comment: My exact requirement is i need to draw only what is getting dynamically updated with also preserving the static data for each frame.
I am able to draw the updated portion using glDrawElements(..) and only that is getting rendered but the not able to preserve and display the static data.
Please can you suggest a way in opengles using which i can preserve the static data and render it along with dynamic data.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

OpenGL does not really support incremental rendering. You need to draw the entire frame every time you are asked to redraw.

The closest I can think of is that you render your static data to an offscreen framebuffer, using a FBO (Frame Buffer Object). You should be able to find plenty of examples online and in books if you look for keywords like "OpenGL FBO". You will be using calls like `glGenFramebuffers()`, `glBindFramebuffer()`, `glFramebufferTexture2D()`, etc.

Once you rendered the static content into an FBO, you can copy it to the default framebuffer at the start of each redraw, and then render the dynamic content on top of it. This can be a worthwhile method if rendering the static content is very expensive. Otherwise, doing the copy from FBO to default framebuffer can be more expensive than simply re-rendering the static content each time.

The above is pretty easy if the static content is in the background, and the dynamic content is completely in front of it. If static and dynamic content overlap, it gets trickier. You will then have to restore the depth buffer resulting from rendering the static content each time before starting to render the dynamic content. I can't think of a good way to do that in ES 2.0. The features to do this relatively smoothly (depth textures, `glBlitFramebuffer`) are only in ES 3.0 and later.

There is one other option that I don't think is very appealing, but I wanted to mention it for completeness sake: EGL defines a `EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR` attribute that can be set to `EGL_BUFFER_PRESERVED`. One big caveat is that it's optional, and not supported on all devices. It also only preserves the color buffer, and not auxiliary buffers, like the depth buffer. If you want to read up on it anyway, see [eglSwapBuffers](https://www.khronos.org/registry/egl/sdk/docs/man/html/eglSwapBuffers.xhtml) and [eglSurfaceAttrib](https://www.khronos.org/registry/egl/sdk/docs/man/html/eglSurfaceAttrib.xhtml).

Comment: Hi Reto, had one query i am using using single buffer will opengl FBO work fine with that?

Comment: OpenGL ES does not support single buffering. In full OpenGL you can have only a single buffer, and draw directly to the front buffer. But that feature does not exist in ES.

Comment: @Reto Koradi Thank you very much for your detailed answer. Just one clarification: If I need just to show an image for 3 seconds (the window shall display just that image, it never changes), rendering picture 60 fps (thus loading CPU/GPU) is considered OK? I mean calling mySprite.draw(myBatch) each time from render() method of ScreenAdapter in libGDX app? Shall I care about performance and invent any optimization (in a Desktop application) at all? My picture is a 1920x1080 shown on almost full-screen window, does it mean that "rendering the static content is very expensive" in my case?