# Is LibGDX SpriteBatch draw() smart enough not to redraw 100% exactly same sprite at each render() call?

Tags: java, libgdx, render

Is LibGDX SpriteBatch draw() smart enough not to redraw 100% exactly same sprite at each render() call?

```
 public void render(float delta) {
            Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
            Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

            if (shallFadeOut) {  // becomes true when sound message finishes
                doFadingOut();
                showNextScreen();
                dispose(); 
            } else {
                batch.begin();
                // introSprite is a static image - it never changes a pixel (splash screen)
                // I need to paint it once and then just wait until sound message finishes
                // DON'T NEED TO REDRAW IT EVERY render() cycle 60 times/sec (~60 fpm)
                introSprite.draw(batch);  
                batch.end();
            }
}
```

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25478868/how-to-redraw-partially-in-opengl-es-2-0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In OpenGL, you typically redraw the whole screen on every frame. It doesn’t make sense to wonder if the batch is smart enough to avoid redrawing the same thing, because it *has* to redraw it to prevent it from disappearing.

If you want to avoid redrawing anything on the screen for a while to save battery on the device, you can use `GDX.graphics.setContinuousRendering(false)` but that means your `render()` method will stop getting called so you must set it back to true using a timer or input callback.

You could alternatively use a Boolean to decide whether to clear the screen with `glClear` and draw stuff, but under the hood, LibGDX will still be requesting OpenGL to copy the screen buffer data between the back buffer and the screen buffer.

Not that drawing a single sprite is super trivial and probably not worth a second of thought about optimizing it.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid that I do not think any accounting is done by the `Batch` between batching render steps to see if a texture was already loaded and is ready to be rendered, but the texture itself might.

The batching is intended for cases where you are drawing duplicates of the same thing in the same render step so that you are not unnecessarily context switching between sprites and having to reload data to your graphics card.

The batch is as I am sure you know defined by the `begin` and `end` calls you are using, and it depends on you actually rendering all of the sprites of a particular type one after the other without jumping to render something else. This can be seen int he batch draw code [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/SpriteBatch.java#L895-L900), but for readability the relevant lines are below:

```
Texture texture = region.texture;
if (texture != lastTexture) {
    switchTexture(texture);
} else if (idx == vertices.length) {
    flush();
}
```

To take advantage of the batch - you should be grouping the rendering of all your sprite types, and between steps, the batch does not offer any efficiencies by design as far as I can tell.

But, between batching steps or game loops, when a texture is bound, it uses a fixed target and handle as can be seen [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/28540863c5e882ce6cf0a3e4ea16f0ece00b3b43/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/GLTexture.java#L71-L73). This means that if all you are drawing is a single sprite for several render loops, libgdx should be using your memory and graphics card as efficiently as can be expected.